# Can you use both strong and retain in the same property declaration?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, llvm

I've recently started working on someone else's code base and I've come across a lot of this

```
@property (strong, retain) TYPE *iVar;
```

I've never seen both Strong and Retain used in the same property declaration. I'm surprised that it even compiles, as retain already implies strong.

The project uses arc, and is a few months old so legacy isn't the problem here, the deployment target is iOS6.

Is there any valid reason why you would want to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason to use property declarations with both `retain` and `strong` - [according to Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html), the two are synonyms:

> The keywords `weak` and `strong` are introduced as new declared property attributes, as shown in the following examples.

```
// The following declaration is a synonym for: @property(retain) MyClass *myObject;
@property(strong) MyClass *myObject;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ARC then just use strong.

Mixing the two may be allowed now but may produce compiler warnings / errors in the future. Not to mention it looks really odd.